# Does Spring JDBC provide any protection from SQL injection attacks?

Tags: spring, sql-injection, jdbctemplate

Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) abstraction provides a lot of functionality, but can it be used in such a way that provides protection from SQL injection attacks?

For example, like the kind of protection you would get using [PreparedStatement](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java#Prepared_Statements) with properly defined parameterization.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It most certainly does. This example is straight from the Spring 3.0 docs (but is the same in 2.*):

```java
String lastName = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject( 
        "select last_name from t_actor where id = ?", 
        String.class, 1212L);
```

As you can see, it *strongly* favors prepared statements (which it must be using behind the scenes for you): you specify the parameters with placeholders (`?`) and supply an array of objects to fill into the parameters. (The last parameter is the type of the expected result, but that's not very relevant for this question.)

You can also use a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and supply the parameters in a `Map`, which is perhaps less efficient but definitely more mnemonic.

Comment: Cool - the main thing is that the use of parameterized methods in Spring's API definitely map onto parameterized methods in underlying Java PreparedStatements in such a way that the protection is preserved.

Comment: They should do; Spring's all about implementing Best Practices in a more convenient way, and using a PreparedStatement has been advised for… well, I remember it being advised in the first version of JDBC I encountered back in Java 1.1, despite being rather fussy. (I don't know if all JDBC drivers get it right, but if one doesn't I'd consider that an _excellent_ reason for not using it.)

Comment: Hi, does `this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject( 
        "select last_name from t_actor where id = " + id); ` is safe as well?

Comment: @TheUnreal Of course it depends on where your id comes from and what it's type is on what is possible as an SQL injection, but it could definitely be exploited. 

Let's say id is a String, and you pass it down directly from what the client sends you (so either an input field, or an explicitly altered get request, or whatever, ...), they could make id = "someId; DROP TABLE t_actor;". Depending on your underlying DB and what it allows, they could potentially drop a table, execute any other arbitrarily chosen query, ...

Better safe than sorry, use parameterized queries ;)

Comment: I am using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and I pass input to SQL query with Map. is it safe from SQL Injection? please tell me