# Calling DB stored routines in Spring

Tags: spring, stored-procedures

I have MySQL stored routines and need to call them from my Java Spring application. Currently I do it like this:

```
result = org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(
     "CALL MyRoutine(?, ?);", 
     myRowMapper, 
     parameterOne, 
     parameterTwo);
```

Questions:

- Is this a recommended way of doing this, in terms of reliability, security and performance? Or is there another best practice approach?
- Is this method safeguarding against SQL injection attacks?
- The parameter order is important, making me vulnerable to confusing it. Some way to get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around the parameter order by using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html

Comment: Thanks. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254534/does-spring-jdbc-provide-any-protection-from-sql-injection-attacks, this approach also protects against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

1. The approach you chose uses vendor syntax instead of JDBC call syntax (see [Syntax of JDBC Connection prepareCall SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382100/syntax-of-jdbc-connection-preparecall-sql)) and is therefore not portable across databases (this may not be an issue for you). Spring JDBC offers [many different ways](https://github.com/marschall/stored-procedure-proxy/wiki/Comparison-with-other-frameworks#spring-jdbc) to call a stored procedure, there is no obvious best approach.
2. This is safe against SQL injection unless the stored procedure itself is vulnerable to SQL injection (concatenates the parameters into a query).
3. You can bind parameters for stored procedures by name instead of index using the `#setX(String, X)` methods on `CallableStatement`. This may not be supported by your database driver. This is different from `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` which still binds by index. Also note that `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` has some overhead as it parses and rewrites your query.