# Syntax of JDBC Connection prepareCall SQL

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am reading the [JavaDocs for `Connection#prepareCall`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall(java.lang.String)):

> sql - an SQL statement that may contain one or more '?' parameter placeholders. Typically this statement is specified using JDBC call escape syntax.

According to this popular [mkyong JDBC tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-in-parameter-example/), I see the method executed like so:

```
String insertStoreProc = "{call insertDBUSER(?,?,?,?)}";
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(insertStoreProc);
```

I am wondering:

1. Why is the string encapsulated in curly braces (`{ ... }`)?
2. Why does `call` proceed the name of the procedure?

**Most importantly**: is `{ call <nameOfProcedure> }` the correct syntax for executing all stored procedures across all JDBC drivers? Or is `{ call ... }` specific to a particular type of driver?

Are there variations of this procedure invocation syntax? For instance, are there scenarios/drivers where one might pass `"{ execute <nameOfProcedure> }"` into the `prepareCall` method? Is there documentation on any of this?

---

#### Update:

According to `CallableStatement`, JDBC offers 2 valid syntaxes for calling procs in a standard way, across all drivers:

```
{?= call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}
```

And:

```
{call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}
```

But it is still unclear as to when to use either (that is: when to preprend `call` with `?=`).

Comment: You should read [`java.sql.CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), where all these questions are answered.

Comment: Thanks @LuiggiMendoza (+1) - please see my update and followup question regarding the use of `?=`. Thanks again!

Comment: Uh... read the proper JDBC driver for the specific database engine, where the usage of one or another is explained.

Comment: Thanks again @LuiggiMendoza (+1) - but your answer and the JavaDoc link for `CallableStatement` now have me a bit concerned. (1) If I'm reading the JavaDocs correctly, it seems like JDBC only allows a **single column or value** to be returned by a stored procedure. Is this true, or am I misreading the JavaDocs? If I am reading them correctly, this seems like a horrible limitation, as I might have my procedure returning many columns across many tables!

Comment: And (2) I highly doubt that using `?=` is driver-specific, there just wouldn't be any value to that, from an API perspective. Say I have a procedure called `sp_my_proc`, and I have it defined/installed in 2 different RDBMSes (say, HSQLDB and MySQL), and in both cases the proc returns the same columns and JDBC-compliant data types. Then if HSQLDB requires me to use `?=` when I execute `sp_my_proc`, and, MySQL does not, it seems like JDBC should be able to allow me to just go without `?=` altogether and let the driver figure out what to do with the proc output. Thoughts?

Comment: That's how a stored procedure works. A SQL stored procedure can only return a single value **as `RETURN`**, and it could have OUT parameters. The return value from a stored procedure is different from the `ResultSet`(s) it could maintain opened when being called, but this is database engine specific. JDBC provides the most generic way to access to the database engine, but it depends on the database engine and on the JDBC driver implementation the support of all the features, specific vendor features or being an incomplete database engine.

Comment: By the way, these are comments, not answers.

Comment: Thanks again @LuiggiMendoza (+2 for both) - so, to confirm, generally-speaking, stored procedures have: (1) an optional, but single, `RETURN VALUE`, AND (2) optional, but n-ary `OUTPUT` values that can be returned to the JDBC client (the application using JDBC)? If so, can I assume it would be safe for me to forgo using `?=` altogether, and just make sure my procs always export the `OUTPUT` fields back into the JDBC `ResultSet`? Thanks again so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JDBC specification](https://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html), section 13.4 Escape Syntax defines a number of escapes called JDBC escapes. These escapes are wrapped in curly braces. The specification for the call escape is:

> If a database supports stored procedures, they can be invoked using JDBC escape syntax as follows:
>
> ```
> {call <procedure_name> [(<argument-list>)]}
> ```
>
> or, where a procedure returns a result parameter:
>
> ```
> {? = call <procedure_name> [(<argument-list>)]}
> ```
>
> The square brackets indicate that the (argument-list) portion is optional. Input arguments may be either literals or parameter markers. See “Setting Parameters” on page 108 for information on parameters.

This is also documented on [`java.sql.CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)

So the name `call` and the curly braces are both specified in the JDBC specification.

As to the second part of your question. JDBC is a specification that tries to be database independent as much as possible and to do this it - usually - defaults to the SQL standard. IIRC the SQL specification specifies that a stored procedure either has no return value or a single return value. If the stored procedure has no return value, then you use the first call syntax. If the stored procedure has a single return value, then you use the second.

Stored procedures can also have `OUT` parameters (not to be confused with result sets), which are defined in the normal argument list.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Rotteveel (+1) - I wish I could upvote this more! One quick followup question: it seems that there are apparently **three** types of outputs JDBC supports from stored procedures: (1) Return Values, (2) Output Params and (3) Result Sets. Does the JDBC spec weigh-in on where/when/how these outputs should be used? In other words, is there a JDBC standard for what constitutes a Return Value vs Output Param vs Result Set? Thanks again so much!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja This isn't really specified in JDBC, I believe you need to look at the SQL specification for that. But in general: return value: the single value returned by a `RETURN value` statement in a SP, `OUT` parameters get a value once in the SP (or at least: the last value assigned to the `OUT` parameter is the one you get back). Result sets are just that: rows returned from the stored procedure (multiple result sets are possible, if the DB supports it!). ResultSet fields are **not** supposed to be defined as parameters.